# "This page isn't working 10.110.15.17 didn’t send any data" after pressing "Submit" button

Tags: python, http, webserver, httpserver

I'm currently taking a Udacity's course Full Stack Foundations. One lesson in this course wants me to make a web server for a user to input something. Then, the message will be displayed. on the screen. The user can "Submit" constantly, but it will only show the message that the user last submitted. I am able to see the webpage with "Hello!", input box, and "Submit" button. But after I enter something in the box and click the button, it shows "This page isn't working. 10.110.15.17 didn’t send any data". The console also didn't throw my any error. It also seems like the output is correct. I really couldn't figure out my mistake. Could anyone help me?

Below is my full code,

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import cgi

class webserverHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        try:
            if self.path.endswith('/hello'):
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
                self.end_headers()

                output = ""
                output += "<html><body>"
                output += "<h1>Hello!</h1>"
                output += "<form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='/hello'>"
                output += "<h2>What would you like me to say?</h2>"
                output += "<input name='message' type='text' >"
                output += "<input type='submit' value='Submit'>"
                output += "</form>"
                output += "</body></html>"
                self.wfile.write(output.encode())
                return

        except IOError:

            self.send_error(404, 'File Not Found %s' % self.path)

    def do_POST(self):
        try:
            self.send_response(301)
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
            self.end_headers

            c_type, p_dict = cgi.parse_header(
                self.headers.get('Content-Type')
            )
            content_len = int(self.headers.get('Content-length'))
            p_dict['boundary'] = bytes(p_dict['boundary'], "utf-8")
            p_dict['CONTENT-LENGTH'] = content_len
            message_content = ''
            if c_type == 'multipart/form-data':
                fields = cgi.parse_multipart(self.rfile, p_dict)
                message_content = fields.get('message')

            output = ""
            output += "<html><body>"
            output += " <h2> Okay, how about this: </h2>"
            output += "<h1>%s</h1>" % message_content[0]
            output += "<form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='/hello'>"
            output += "<h2>What would you like me to say?</h2>"
            output += "<input name='message' type='text'>"
            output += "<input type='submit' value='Submit'>"
            output += "</form>"
            output += "</body></html>"

            self.wfile.write(output.encode())
            print(output)
            return

        except:
            pass


def main():
    try:
        port = 8080
        server = HTTPServer(('', port), webserverHandler)
        print('Server running on port %s' % port)
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('^C entered, stopping web server...')
        server.socket.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Inside the console:

```
Server running on port 8080
10.110.15.17 - - [22/Dec/2021 23:53:54] "GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 200 -
10.110.15.17 - - [22/Dec/2021 23:53:58] "POST /hello HTTP/1.1" 301 -
<html><body> <h2> Okay, how about this: </h2><h1>hello!!!!!</h1><form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='/hello'><h2>What would you like me to say?</h2><input name='message' type='text'><input type='submit' value='Submit'></form></body></html>
^C entered, stopping web server...
```

the web page will only show up if the path ends with '/hello'.

ps: I'm using Python 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I forgot parenthesis after `self.end_headers`...

Below is the full code that works:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import cgi

class webserverHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        try:
            if self.path.endswith('/hello'):
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
                self.end_headers()

                output = ""
                output += "<html><body>"
                output += "<h1>Hello!</h1>"
                output += "<form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='/hello'>"
                output += "<h2>What would you like me to say?</h2>"
                output += "<input name='message' type='text' >"
                output += "<input type='submit' value='Submit'>"
                output += "</form>"
                output += "</body></html>"
                self.wfile.write(output.encode())
                return

        except IOError:

            self.send_error(404, 'File Not Found %s' % self.path)

    def do_POST(self):
        try:
            self.send_response(301)
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
            self.end_headers()

            c_type, p_dict = cgi.parse_header(
                self.headers.get('Content-Type')
            )
            content_len = int(self.headers.get('Content-length'))
            p_dict['boundary'] = bytes(p_dict['boundary'], "utf-8")
            p_dict['CONTENT-LENGTH'] = content_len
            message_content = ''
            if c_type == 'multipart/form-data':
                fields = cgi.parse_multipart(self.rfile, p_dict)
                message_content = fields.get('message')

            output = ""
            output += "<html><body>"
            output += " <h2> Okay, how about this: </h2>"
            output += "<h1>%s</h1>" % message_content[0]
            output += "<form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='/hello'>"
            output += "<h2>What would you like me to say?</h2>"
            output += "<input name='message' type='text'>"
            output += "<input type='submit' value='Submit'>"
            output += "</form>"
            output += "</body></html>"

            self.wfile.write(output.encode())
            print(output)
            return

        except:
            pass


def main():
    try:
        port = 8080
        server = HTTPServer(('', port), webserverHandler)
        print('Server running on port %s' % port)
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('^C entered, stopping web server...')
        server.socket.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```